# Linux timer hangs sometime and stops at 1ns

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have an embedded board with PowerPC 5200 running Realtime Linux with version 2.6.33.

My application is using one high-resolution timer in Linux for alarms. This timer sometimes didn’t expire. The problem happens very rarely, it may go many months between each time it happens on a system.

The timer is set by function `timer_settime` with absolute time.
I have done some interesting observations when the timer didn’t expire:

- Function `timer_gettime` returns remaining time 1ns.
- Active timers are checked by displaying file `/proc/timer_list` and the `timer_list` didn’t show this timer in the active timer list.

I have looked into the Linux source and found a possible scenario:

The function `timer_gettime` ends up in function `common_timer_get` (`posix-timers.c`). Function `common_timer_get` returns `it_value.tv_nsec = 1` if timer is active and remaining time is `<= 0`. This means that the timer has counted down and the timer state must be 'enqueued' or 'callback'.

I suppose that it is in state 'callback', that means it is running in function `__run_hrtimer` (`hrtimer.c`). Function `__run_hrtimer` is calling function `__remove_hrtimer` that remove the timer from timer active list before it changes timer state from 'enqueued' to 'callback'.

Several functions are called in function `__run_hrtimer` between changing timer state to 'callback' and the end of the function where the state 'callback' is cleared. If it is hanging here, the function `timer_gettime` may return 1ns while the timer is not on the active list. Here it is calling several functions in Linux kernel and the callback function in the application.

I have checked the callback function in my application. It is signaling a semaphore and setting the timer again on the same thread. I can't see why that should not work.

Is there someone that has seen a similar case?

Is there someone that has an idea of what is going wrong here?

Comment: Is there a race condition somewhere? Can you show some code?

Comment: We are using Kernel 2.6.33 with RT patches and are having the same issue. If checked in the callback, the timer is not zero - 1ns is remaining.